# Unity Videoplayer how to pause and play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Im trying to make a Vuforia Video Player with virtual buttons but when I try to pause and play it gives me and error. I looked at some forums and some question that is old but they didnt fix my problem. Error is:

```
Assets\vp_time.cs(23,9): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'VideoPlayer.Pause()'
Assets\vp_time.cs(27,9): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'VideoPlayer.Play()'
```

Code is:

```
﻿using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;
using Vuforia;

public class vp_time : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject vbBtnObj;
    public GameObject vbVpObj;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        vbBtnObj = GameObject.Find("VideoBtn");
        vbBtnObj.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterOnButtonPressed(OnButtonPressed);
        vbBtnObj.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterOnButtonReleased(OnButtonReleased);
        vbVpObj.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
    }

    public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb){
        VideoPlayer.Pause();
    }

    public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb){
        VideoPlayer.Play();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as the error says `VideoPlayer` is a type. It has no `static` method `VideoPlayer.Play`. You need a reference to an **instance** of type `VideoPlayer` and call the method on that instance.

```
vbVpObj.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
```

this line does absolutely nothing!

You rather wanted to store this reference in a field

```
// Drag this already in via the Inspector in Unity
[SerializeField] private VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
```

or do

```
private void Start ()
{
    ...

    // As fallback get the reference on runtime ONCE
    if(!videoPlayer) videoPlayer = vbVpObj.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
}
```

and later

```
videoPlayer.Play();
```

and

```
videoPlayer.Pause();
```